# SQL query is changing all names?

Tags: mysql, sql

So i am trying to change a particular name, only the query is changing all the names.

```
UPDATE Team
SET Naam = 'besties'
FROM Team AS T 
INNER JOIN Gebruiker AS G ON T.GebruikerID = G.Id
WHERE (G.Gebruikersnaam = 'toppers')
```

The table "Team" looks like this:

[image: The table Team]

The table "Gebruiker" looks like this
[image: The table Gebruiker]
As you can see in both rows the Name is "besties", the idea is to change the Name only at one row.

In row 1 the Name was first "toppers"

Comment: But you're checking `Gebruikersnaam`, which is not the `Naam` that is displayed in your screenshot. Maybe gebruikers 1 and 10 are both named `toppers`?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes im sure!

Comment: @GolezTrol "Gebruikersnaam" belongs to the table "gebruiker" and "Naam" belongs to the table "Team"

Comment: It would help immensely if you could include (as text, in your question) short `CREATE TABLE` statements showing the *relevant* columns from both tables and then some `INSERT` statements with *sample data*. You have the immense advantage over us currently of being actually able to *run your code* as well as to *inspect your data*.

Comment: Shown SQL code is **synthactically wrong in MySQL**. Check your DBMS carefully.

Comment: the idea is to change the Name only at one row. - Which row ? Lowest id, highest id, or something else. and why is the id and GebruikerID different in the published tables.

Comment: @P.Salmon it don't matter but take where id is 1 in table "Team" as example. De GebruikerID is coupled with the id from the table "Gebruiker".

Comment: @Akina DBMS is not giving me any errors on the code itself.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what do you mean by create Table

Comment: I cannot reproduce you error. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02c4d282fd8e6923dd2e9732dbec136a

Comment: *DBMS is not giving me any errors on the code itself.* This means that you use **NOT** MySQL. Maybe MS SQL (SQL Server)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the syntax you're currently using, but I would write it like this. I think this more clearly conveys that you're only updating Team, and to be exact, only the Team of any of the Gebruikers named 'toppers'.

Instead of `in` you could use `=`, if it's guaranteed that Gebruikersnaam is unique.

```
UPDATE Team T
SET T.Naam = 'besties'
WHERE
  T.GebruikerID in 
  ( SELECT G.Id 
    FROM Gebruikers G 
    WHERE G.Gebruikersnaam = 'toppers'
  )
```